# how to make div static so it doesnot jump up if screen two big

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this page, http://www.stahlbaron.de/stahl-produkte/ i developed the page with 15'' screen, thats why i didnot see this bug: now i have 27'' screen and once i opened this page, the whole page is getting massed up, because the picture goes up and i cannot figure out why this is happening. please open the page and scale it, then you see the bug. some element is becoming big or small and as a result, some other elements are becoming confused

how can i fix this?

thanks

Comment: [What have yout tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Neysor, i did, ``position: fixed`` and all other properties, but they dont do the job

Comment: set the width of your table. as your screen width is wider now it stretches the table with it. set a width a bit wider than your image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you set the [clear property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) for the div that is holding the image:

```
clear: both;
```

Comment: wow! magic! :). working. thanks in tons